# ADO.NET - using AsQueryable() in entity framework

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

I'm using this generic method to query for the info from my tables :

```
public virtual IQueryable<TObject> All()
{
    return DbSetFilterDeleted.AsQueryable();
}
```

but for one of my tables I need to make `JOIN` so I need to modify this. I have a little experience with .NET at all but from my research I understand that `AsQueryable()` can be modified exactly for to serve these kind of purposes.

My question is how to modify it so that I can add to my query additional data, let say `Post.Content` where `BlogId = FK_BlogId`.

Comment: If `DbSetFilterDeleted` already implements `IQueryable<TObject>`, then the `.AsQueryable()` does not add anything. If `DbSetFilterDeleted` does not implement `IQueryable<TObject>`, then `.AsQueryable()` is harmful: any operations on the result will be performed on the client, not on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to employ `Include` statement in your queries.
For instance, if you are querying `Post`s and want to join related `Content`s;

```
myContext.Posts.Include("Content");
```

and this will return an object of type `IQueryable<Post>`.